# How to stop propagate next inline function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this needed html code:

```
//html code
<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Save" onclick="validate(event, document.thisForm); return submitForm(document.thisForm);"></a>
<form name="thisForm">
    //some stuff without submit button and required inputs
</form
```

My JS looks like this:

```
function validate(event, form)
{
    var error = '';

    var $inputs = jQuery(form).find(':input[required]');

    $inputs.each( function() {
        if(jQuery(this).val().length === 0) {
            error += 'missing value';
            return;
        }
    });

    if (error !== '') {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();

        window.alert(error);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Problem is that its impossible stop to call submitForm function when something is wrong at validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `onclick` event handler to:

```
return validate(event, document.thisForm) && submitForm(document.thisForm);
```